# Power BI Column Mapping does not show the values

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am a newbie to Power BI, I am trying to learn how to create a workflow. As a first step, I created an ADLS Gen2 container and uploaded a sample json to the container. Json has only one key/value. Something like

```
{ "DOMINO_API_KEY": "val1"}
```

I am able to establish the connection to my container through Power BI, transform the JSON to a table like in the below screenshot
[image]
Then I clicked next to create the Map table. It shows me to enter the table name etc
[image]
When I created the table, I do not see the value in the table which I transformed earlier.  What am I doing wrong here, can anyone help?

Thanks,
Tintu

Comment: I initially posted the question as powerapp then it was suggested me to edit to power bi. I am a new user so I don't really understand the difference between power app and power bi much. But this screenshot was taken navigating from https://make.powerapps.com/

Comment: The PowerPlatform has so much convergence right now, its tough to tell where you're entering the product looking at just a screenshot. These PowerQuery screens are present *natively* in PowerBI and via a link from PowerApps/DataFlows. That being said, is there anything [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/data-platform/create-and-use-dataflows#using-dataflows-stored-in-azure-data-lake-storage-gen2) that helps?

Comment: I am the op. I still could not get it working. Any help will be much appreciated